# put-metric-data command does not create plot in cloud watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to plot a new metric using Amazon CloudWatch.

I have been referring to the [AWS CLI documentation for `put-metric-data`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html).

I have created the following test JSON:

```
[{"MetricName":"total_log_count" ,"Timestamp":"Saturday, April 08, 2017 00:00:00 AM","Value":73566,"Unit": "Count"},{"MetricName":"total_log_count" ,"Timestamp":"Sunday, April 09, 2017 00:00:00 AM","Value":61385,"Unit": "Count"},{"MetricName":"total_log_count" ,"Timestamp":"Monday, April 10, 2017 00:00:00 AM","Value":63467,"Unit": "Count"},{"MetricName":"total_log_count" ,"Timestamp":"Tuesday, April 11, 2017 00:00:00 AM","Value":60585,"Unit": "Count"},{"MetricName":"total_log_count" ,"Timestamp":"Wednesday, April 12, 2017 00:00:00 AM","Value":61951,"Unit": "Count"}]
```

and executed the JSON file with below command from an EC2 instance:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "Usage Metrics" --metric-data file://test.json
```

The command is executed successfully and the new metric is created in CloudWatch but the graph is not getting displayed.

Have I done anything wrong in the JSON or is there any log feature that will help me to debug data in CloudWatch?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your metric json command at first sight. Are you sure you're looking at the right region in the console? You can see what region the CLI is talking to by typing aws configure. Make sure you go to the same region in the AWS Console.

Comment: If the graph is displayed but it is empty, wait a little longer. It sometimes takes a while for the metric to be displayed. If the metric is for a previous timestamp (that is, for data that is not "now"), adjust the display to show more data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply . It has worked but it has taken more than an hour atleast .